# Does the word "glitz" have a negative connotation?

Tags: meaning, connotation

On Google, it is defined as something "extravagant but superficial display", or "to make something glamorous or showy". That doesn't sound negative to me; however, other sources make it sound as if it's negative by adding the word "ostentatious".

According to dictionary.com, ostentatious is "characterized by or given to pretentious or conspicuous show in an attempt to impress others". Further looking up the definition of pretentious states it is "characterized by assumption of dignity or importance, especially when **exaggerated** or **undeserved**".

After reading these definitions, glitz does not sound like a positive connotation to me at all. Is there another way of looking at this particular word that is known to be generally positive?

Comment: "Superficial" is not generally a complementary way to describe something (other than perhaps a paint).

Comment: "Extravagant" isn't generally a compliment either, and "showy" also has negative connotations, e.g. being ostentatious.

Comment: @HotLicks: you presumably mean *complimentary*? Ironically, in this particular case "superficial" is actually used in a complementary way ;-)

Comment: Please don't fool yourself that "On Google…" anything. Google never provides answers; only ever links to answers and it's the links and answers you need to cite, not the fact that you found them via Google. Childishly, you might compare that to finding answers in bookshops or libraries, rather than specific books…
  
To you, how is "ostentatious" negative - even if it is "characterized by or given to pretentious or conspicuous show in an attempt to impress others"?

Could you take the Question to a site that deals with writing style?

Comment: "Deeper" search does not necessarily lead one to the deeper meaning. *Glitz* **is** negative.  "... this particular word that is known to be generally positive," says who?

Comment: Today, *pomp and pageantry* may not invoke images of "stately or magnificent display; ceremonial splendour," only of a "vain display" (def. from Collins).

Comment: Google has no definitions… only links to definitions elsewhere, whose clarity and value depend on the search term you didn’t post.

“Glitz” is broadly *an* "extravagant but superficial display" though in decades listening I’ve never heard “to glitz” as a verb (nor does Google seem to) - but consider some synonymous phrases…

To gloss over…; to whitewash… literally neutral; idiomatically, negative. 

How did "ostentatious" get into this?

For "glitz", search q=razzle+dazzle+em&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB779GB779&oq=razzle+dazzle+em&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.21255j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8